# Boto3 not returning all the APIs available in my AWS APIGateway Management Console

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to return *API id*'s of all the APIs that are available in my account of a specific region.

But its returning very few while I have many more in the *AWS APIGateway Management Console*.

#### My Code

```py
client=boto3.client('apigateway','us-east-1')
data = client.get_apis()
results = data['Items']

while "NextToken" in data:
   data = self.client_conn.get_apis(NextToken=data['NextToken'])
   results.extend(data['Items'])
```

Comment: `self.client_conn` is undefined. So what is that?

Comment: I did not find the method `get_apis`  in Amazon's Boto3 Documentation, only [`APIGateway.Client.get_rest_apis(**kwargs)`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.get_rest_apis) seems close to your question. What do you want to get exactly?

Comment: Hi Marcin, Please find my updated code below, I was trying to get api id's of all the apis available in my account in us-east-1 region, but the below code is not returning all the id’s

client=boto3.client('apigatewayv2','us-east-1')
data = client.get_apis()
results = data['Items']

while "NextToken" in data:
   data = client.get_apis(NextToken=data['NextToken'])
   results.extend(data['Items'])

Comment: APIGateway.Client.get_rest_apis(**kwargs) this only returns REST apis details, what about other apis like HTTP, Websocket?

Comment: @hc_dev `get_apis()` is in APIGatewayV2
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigatewayv2.html#ApiGatewayV2.Client.get_apis

Answer (score 0):

modify this line:

```
data = client.get_apis()
```

for:

```
data = client.get_apis(limit=500)
```

max number is 500.

use the one you need

Comment: small change in code data =  client.get_rest_apis(limit=500)